# Converting binary (bytes) to str and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a binary data such as in a `dataframe`'s column :

`b'x\x9c\xd4\x14Q\xd3\xf7\x92\x8b\x89 \x01\xc3)B\x8c\x80\x91#\x86\xfb\xa6\x9b\x10\xce\x00\x86p\x85Cr\x11\xd8p\x84\xcc\x12<A\x17!'`

I need an idea how do I convert it to string for each `binary` column value only, as this `dataframe` need to be converted to json type and passed as a result of a rest api endpoint.

Here is how I do return `dataframe` in json format( doing it to `dataframe` with binary will raise exception):
`return json.loads(df.to_json(orient='table'))`
Whereas `df` is a dataframe

I would of course will want to know how to convert back the binary values from string representation of `bytes` to `bytes`- binary again.

Comment: What was the encoding scheme used for this string? You can use `df['col'].str.decode(<your encoding>)` or something similar.

Comment: @coldspeed: not sure I understood what you mean in scheme, I'm new to pandas .Anyway I think we can assume the binary is result of `pickle.dumps()` method

Comment: Then use `df['col'].apply(pickle.loads)`?

Comment: @coldspeed: Is there a way to extract with pandas just the columns which has this type, or I should do it on native python code?

Comment: In order to convert a bunch of bytes into any string you need to know the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the encoding used to create those bytes. The default encoding is platform specific, you check yours:

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding() # 'utf-8' on macos python 3.7
```

If you pass a string to `pickle.dumps` it will encode it using the default encoding, if you want to use another encoding you can encode the string before passing it to `pickle.dumps` (as an example).

```
In [2]: pickle.dumps('höy') # will be 'utf-8' encoded by default
Out[2]: b'\x80\x03C\x04h\xc3\xb6yq\x00.'

In [3]: 'höy'.encode('utf-8')
Out[3]: b'h\xc3\xb6y' # compare with the previous output

In [4]: pickle.dumps('höy'.encode('latin1'))
Out[4]: b'\x80\x03C\x03h\xf6yq\x00.'

In [5]: 'höy'.encode('latin1')
Out[5]: b'h\xf6y' # compare with the previous output
```

Based on the encodings you can decode your strings:

```
In [1]: 'höy'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
Out[1]: 'höy'

In [2]: 'höy'.encode('latin-1').decode('latin-1')
Out[2]: 'höy'
```

Using the wrong encoding will result in failure or wrong result:

```
In [3]: 'höy'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
Out[3]: 'hÃ¶y'
```

And not every random bunch of bytes is an encoded string:

```
In [6]: pickle.dumps('höy').decode('utf-8')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2b1872a5aa1a> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.dumps('höy').decode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```